# windows store app crashes when launched from charm bar. works well otherwise

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, charms-bar

windows store app crashes when launched from charm bar. works well otherwise

can anyone tell how to debug the app and launch in visual studio like from charm bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change settings of your project. There's a setting called "Start waiting for program activation" (or something similar, on a PC without VS) on the debugging tab of your project settings. That way, if you switch to the start screen and tap on the icon or invoke your application using the search charm, the debugger attaches to the process.

Comment: Here's a link to that setting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781607.aspx#BKMK__Optional__Delay_starting_the_debug_session